# iOS method in data controller isn't being called

Tags: ios, methods, error-handling

I am trying to call a method in my data controller object to load the data for my application, but for some reason it is not being called. Below is what I have done to initialize it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

ViewController:

header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DetailViewController;
@class DataController;

#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import "JointCAD.h"

@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) DataController *dataController;

@end
```

implementation file:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "DataController.h"

@implementation TableViewController

@synthesize dataController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {

[dataController refreshData];

}

@end
```

Data Controller:

header file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JointCAD.h"
#import "JointCADXMLParser.h"
#import "TFHpple.h"

@interface DataController : NSObject {

    TFHpple *xpathParser;
}

- (void)refreshData;

- (void)initXMLParser;

- (void)noCallsMessage;

- (void)noInternetMessage;

@end
```

implementation file:

```
#import "DataController.h"

@implementation DataController

XMLParser *xmlParser;

- (void)refreshData {

NSLog("Some Method");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is 'dataController' Object being set by some other class? - I believe that's why you have set it as a property? Right?

If No, then Remove the property,@synthesize of 'dataController' and try simple allocation of your 'dataController' object and then try calling your method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmmm I was using ray wenderlichs push notification tutorial as an example and that is how he access his data model. I shouldn't have to allocate it everytime I want to access it....

Answer (score 0):

You either need to initialize "DataController" prior to actually calling one of it's methods, or you need to make the method, "refreshData" a class by changing it's "-" to a "+".

If you need an instance callback instead. You need to rewrite "viewDidLoad" like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

DataController *dataController = [[DataController alloc] init];
[dataController refreshData];

}
```

And get rid of the property declaration of dataController because you haven't initialized it. If you would prefer a property declaration instead, simply allocate the viewcontroller prior to calling a function from it.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
dataController = [[DataController alloc] init];
[dataController refreshData];

}
```

One last thing to note is that I (and probably Ray) assume that you're using a storyboard configuration. If you are using a xib configuration, you need to add `initWithNibName:` to each initialization of the view controller.

I hope that's helpful!